# using razor to point to a rich text editor in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

Hi i am using umbraco and i have created a rich text editor which holds some info i want to show.. now i am not to sure how to point to it using razor.. i want to point to its id but again i am getting confused.

My rich text editor is called 'Terms and conditions' and it is a children of another page.. i have tried to do something like this..

```
   <umbraco:macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
          @inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext             
          @{ var termsHtml = Model.Children.Where("Name == \"Terms and Conditions\""); }                    
           @if (termsHtml.Count() == 0) { termsHtml = Model.Parent.Children.Where("Name == \"Terms and Conditions\""); }                    
            @if (termsHtml.Count() == 1){    @Html.Raw(@termsHtml.First().GetProperty("htmlContent").Value) }                   
     </umbraco:macro>
```

i dont want to do this messy macros i want to know a way in razor i can just point to the children rich text editor id without having to hard code a name in it.. plus this macro does not even work.

Any help would be great..
Thanks

Comment: Is your template a masterpage or a razor file?

Comment: masterpage @MortenOC